# Proving that $(\vec a \times \vec b) \times (\vec a \times \vec c)=\vec a(\vec a \cdot \vec b \times \vec c)$ using index notation.

Tags: vectors, tensors

I'm trying to prove that  $$(\vec a \times \vec b) \times (\vec a \times \vec c)=\vec a(\vec a \cdot \vec b \times \vec c)$$ using index notation (i.e. Einstein sumnmation notation).

Here's what I've done so far:
$$\begin{align} (\vec a \times \vec b) \times (\vec a \times \vec c) &=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k\varepsilon_{ilm}a_lc_m \\ \ \\&=[\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilm}]a_ja_lb_kc_m \\ \ \\&=[\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}]a_ja_lb_kc_m \\ \ \\&=(\delta_{jl}a_j)(\delta_{km}b_k)a_lc_m-(\delta_{jm}a_j)(\delta_{kl}b_k)a_lc_m \\ \ \\&=a_lb_ma_lc_m-a_mb_lc_m \\ \ \\&=a_l[a_lb_mc_m-a_mb_lc_m] \\ \ \\&=\vec a[(\vec b \cdot \vec c)\vec a-(\vec a \cdot \vec c) \vec b],\end{align}$$ but I'm stuck on how to proceed from here.

Any hints/tips?

P.S. I'm trying to do this **just** using index notation, so I want to avoid vector identities (like the one for $\vec a \cdot \vec b \times \vec c$).

Comment: are you sure of your first equality? it seems to me that you wrote the scalar product of both vector product.

Comment: Just to point out, you've simplified it down to showing that $$\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})=(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{a}-(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b}.$$ That's definitely tractable with index notation.

Comment: @Semiclassical to prove this, would it be easier to start out with LHS or RHS? Also, is my first equality correct (mookid is sceptical)?

Comment: In my comment, the LHS.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you! Are my current lines of working correct (in particular, the first equality)?

Comment: @Semiclassical I've written down $\vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c)=a_i \varepsilon_{ijk}b_jc_k$, but what should I do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first equation is wrong: You left out the Levi-Civitta symbol coming from the middle cross product (and thus end up with an expression with no free indices, which you know can't be right).

The correct starting point is

$$
\epsilon_{krp}  (\epsilon_{ijk}a_ib_j)\epsilon_{mnr}a_mc_n) 
$$
which simplifies as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\epsilon_{mnr} (\epsilon_{krp}  \epsilon_{ijk})a_ib_ja_mc_n =\\
\epsilon_{mnr} (\delta_{ri}\delta_{pj}-\delta_{rj}\delta_{pi})a_ib_ja_mc_n =\\
\epsilon_{mnr} \left( a_ra_mb_pc_n - a_pa_mb_rc_n\right) =\\
-\epsilon_{mnr}  a_pa_mb_rc_n = (\epsilon_{mrn}  a_mb_rc_n) a_p = \\
\left( a_m [\epsilon_{mrn}  b_rc_n] \right) a_p =\\
\left( \vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b}\times\vec{c} \right) \vec{a}
\end{array}
$$